# Using TypeScript in Electron renderer process

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron

I have recently had some struggles with using TypeScript efficiently in my Electron projects. I desire to be able to use TypeScript in both the main process and renderer process with the support for a `types.ts` file as well.

The only solution I have found as far is using Webpack's TypeScript support with a configuration similar to the following:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",

  // All electron pages with a source file must be added here
  entry: {
    page1: "./src/app/pages/page1/index.ts",
    page2: "./src/app/pages/page2/index.ts",
    page3: "./src/app/pages/page3/index.ts",
  },
  
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app/build'),
  },
};
```

Using this however feels a bit hacky to me and significantly slows down my workflow due to me having to run Webpack every time I make changes to the project.

I would like to know, is there a better way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could benefit from automatic compilation and reload to speed up your development process. You may have a look at [electron-quick-start-typescript](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript), which compiles TypeScript using `tsc` directly. If you don't need Webpack for reasons other than compiling TypeScript, this approach might work well for you.

###### Automatic compilation

Using `npm run watch` (which calls `tsc -w`) in a separate terminal, TypeScript files are automatically compiled when file changes are detected. You can configure the compilation in `tsconfig.json`.

###### Automatic reload of Electron app

The module [`electron-reload`](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload) detects changed scripts and reloads the BrowserWindows. If the main process script is changed, it restarts the Electron app as a whole.

```
npm install electron-reload
```

Add this to your main process script:

```js
const electronReload = require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
  electron: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'electron', 'dist', 'electron'),
  electronArgv: ['dist/main.js']
});
```

Comment: Ah the problem with this is that I need to compile multiple typescript index.ts files, for each electron page. I cannot just compile one.

Comment: The setup compiles all `*.ts` files.. what are your `index.ts` files? I assume they are used in the renderer process(es)?

Comment: I see, got the compiling working now. Will I have to specify `win.loadFile()`'s path from the build directory or is there a way around that?

Comment: You load the HTML file from wherever it is located, and the HTML file should reference the compiled renderer scripts.

Comment: I am now getting an `exports` is undefined error when running the program, any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, there's too little to go on.. This sounds like a follow-up question, you should check if there are answers already or post a new, self-contained question.